# Condition on Two columns and create third column failed Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data and I want to create a new column with certain conditions. See the following:
DataSets:

```
real,rel
1,0
0,1
1,1
0,1
0,0
0,0
1,1
1,1
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
0,1
1,0
```

The code I tried and the error I received:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
>>> df.loc[df["real"]==0 and df["rel"]==0,"out"] = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1576, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have the condition for the `out` column as:
when `real` is `0` and `rel` is `0`, `out` should be `0`
when `real` is `1` and `rel` is `1`, `out` should be `1`
when `real` is `1` and `rel` is `0`, `out` should be `2`
when `real` is `0` and `rel` is `1`, `out` should be `3`
Please let me know what I can do to fulfill the missing part.
I have checked this: [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Below is the answer for you query:

```
df.loc[(df["real"]==0) & (df["rel"]==0),"out"] = 0
df.loc[(df["real"]==1) & (df["rel"]==1),"out"] = 1
df.loc[(df["real"]==1) & (df["rel"]==0),"out"] = 2
df.loc[(df["real"]==0) & (df["rel"]==1),"out"] = 3
```

Answer (score 5):

On way is using [`np.select`](https://www.google.com/search?q=NUMPY+SELECT&rlz=1C1GCEU_esES820ES820&oq=NUMPY+SELECT&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j35i39j0l2.1718j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). You can start by defining the set of conditions:

```
c1 = (df.real == 0) & (df.rel == 0) 
c2 = (df.real == 1) & (df.rel == 1) 
c3 = (df.real == 1) & (df.rel == 0) 
c4 = (df.real == 0) & (df.rel == 1)
```

And then you can select among `range(4)` according to the result of the conditions:

```
import numpy as np
df['out'] = np.select([c1,c2,c3,c4], range(4))

     real  rel  out
0      1    0    2
1      0    1    3
2      1    1    1
3      0    1    3
4      0    0    0
5      0    0    0
6      1    1    1
7      1    1    1
8      0    0    0
9      0    1    3
10     1    0    2
11     1    1    1
12     0    1    3
13     1    0    2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
when real is 0 and rel is 0, out should be 0
when real is 1 and rel is 1, out should be 1
when real is 1 and rel is 0, out should be 2
when real is 0 and rel is 1, out should be 3
```

These cases can be combined into one statement:

```
df['out'] = df['rel'] + 2*(df['real'] != df['rel'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    real  rel  out
0      1    0    2
1      0    1    3
2      1    1    1
3      0    1    3
4      0    0    0
5      0    0    0
6      1    1    1
7      1    1    1
8      0    0    0
9      0    1    3
10     1    0    2
11     1    1    1
12     0    1    3
13     1    0    2
```

Comment: Nice out of box solution.

Comment: Nice solution indeed

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is create helper DataFrame and merge:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'real': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'rel': [0, 1, 0, 1], 'new': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
print (df1)
   real  rel  new
0     0    0    0
1     0    1    1
2     1    0    2
3     1    1    3

df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df)
    real  rel  new
0      1    0    2
1      0    1    1
2      1    1    3
3      0    1    1
4      0    0    0
5      0    0    0
6      1    1    3
7      1    1    3
8      0    0    0
9      0    1    1
10     1    0    2
11     1    1    3
12     0    1    1
13     1    0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where` to conditionally fill columns:

```
df["new_column"] = np.nan
df["new_column"] = np.where((df["real"]==0) & (df["rel"]==0), 0, df["new_column"])
df["new_column"] = np.where((df["real"]==1) & (df["rel"]==1), 1, df["new_column"])
# ... etc. through the rest of your conditions.
```